# Is it possible to check or validate the value of an xml node using xsd 1.1, with the help of assert and xpath?

Tags: xml, validation, xpath, xsd, assert

I have a generic XML that needs to be validated using an XSD-Schema.
**Unfortunately the structure of the XML is fixed and can not be changed.**

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="RatingRequestShema-V2.xsd">
  <Request>
    <Props id="Info">
        <Prop id="A" type="DATETIME">2017-10-01T09:34:11Z</Prop>
        <Prop id="B" type="ENUM">Test</Prop>
    </Props>
    <Props id="Example">
        <Prop id="C" type="DATE">1980-08-14</Prop>
        <Prop id="D" type="DECIMAL">34,5</Prop>
    </Props>
  </Request>
</Root>
```

XSD-Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Request">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Props" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="Prop" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                                    <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                                                    <xs:attribute name="type" use="required"/>
                                                    <xs:assert test="if (@id eq 'A') then @type eq 'DATETIME'
                                            else if (@id eq 'B') then @type eq 'ENUM' else false()"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="id" use="required">
                                    <xs:simpleType>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                            <xs:enumeration value="Info"/>
                                            <xs:enumeration value="Example"/>   
                                        </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:simpleType>
                                </xs:attribute>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="datetime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="B_Enum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Test_1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Test_2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Test_3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The XSD-Schema now only checks that if the id equals "A" the type needs to be "DATETIME" but it also needs to check if the value "2017-10-01T09:34:11Z" is of type **xs:dateTime**.
The same applies for the other elements.

So the goal is to check that for a certain id only **one** type and only **one** xs:simpleType is valid.

With my current xs:assert expression I can only check if a Prop element has a specific id and type attribute. But I also need to check the value.

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 1):

You don't say explicitly what your question is.  I'll assume the question is "how do I check that the value is of the right type?"

One way would be to put an additional assertion on the declaration for Prop of the general form

```
if (@type = 'DATETIME') then . castable as xs:dateTime
else ...
```

A perhaps simpler approach would be to use conditional type assignment to assign the appropriate type to Prop.